# percentage of installed base

Tags: android, google-analytics

How can i use analytics to find out which graphics skin is most popular among my users?

In the analytics documentation i can only find ways to track events or pages but i think simply tracking "skin X has now been set" does not meet my needs because i do not want users who briefly try out one skin but then stick with another to score points for the "rejected" skin.

So in stead of tracking events I just want to know which portion of my installed base is now using which skin.

Is this even possible with Analytics or do i need a competitor such as Flurry?

Answer (score 0):

With Google Analytics you can Custom Variables. https://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html

In your case you can simple add a custom variable named "skin" with different values. Use a "Visitor" level if you want to track it per visitor.

You can find the results in a "custom vars" tab in google analytics frontend. You will see then multiple tabs "variable 1" "variable 2". Its a bit difficult to find but you will find it!

Comment: thanks but isnt a custom variable just some parameter you pass along with a tracking event? does the visitor level cause the score to be overwritten when the same user sets a new value for the same key?

Comment: Its something different than an event. Events are really counted. For custom vars you want to know "how many of my users have this 'setting'". If you set it to visitor level it will be counted per visitor. So you can use it too see how many of your visitors currently have skin A enabled. However i am not sure about the overriding part.